# LINQ - Putting result in a dictionary(Of String, Integer), where the integer must be 0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, dictionary

I have a LINQ2Entity problem, I want to get the value, string, from a database, so I select `FProducts.Serial_number`, and to end the query, I do `.ToDictionary`.

The problem is, it tells me that it doesn't have sufficient parameters, to convert `ToDictionary`.

So I need something like select `FProducts.Serial_number, Nothing). ToDictionary`.
Also `FProducts.Serial_number, 0).ToDictionary` doesn't work.

Any recommendations?

```
Sub GetStatistics(ByVal ProductNumbers As List(Of String), ByRef Passed As Integer, ByRef FailedProducts As List(Of String))
        Passed = 0
        FailedProducts = Nothing
        Dim tpDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        For Each productNumber As String In ProductNumbers
            Using context As New SelmaEntities
                Dim Table = (From GoodProducts In context.TestResults
                            Where (GoodProducts.Art_no = productNumber)
                            Select GoodProducts.Art_no, GoodProducts.Failed)
                tpDictionary = (From FProducts In context.TestResults
                            Where (FProducts.Art_no = productNumber And FProducts.Failed <> 0)
                            Order By FProducts.Serial_number
                            Select FProducts.Serial_number, ).ToDictionary

            End Using
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code that isn't working?

Comment: Surely, hold on, I'll pastebin it.

Comment: If you are not going to actually use the value then why use a dictionary?

Comment: For a specific purpose, I am going to increment the value of the key, for each failed test point.

Comment: @Reigo: on SO, we make the questions self contained. Code samples should be short enough to go into the question, so that the question remains complete in the face of link rot. (Editing hint: select lines, Ctrl+K)

Comment: Ah, sorry, the first idea of displaying code to me was pastebin, I forgot there was also code block integrated here, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToDictionary` requires [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) as parameters: one to select the dictionary key, one to select the value. So try:

```
tpDictionary = (From FProducts In context.TestResults
                 Where (FProducts.Art_no = productNumber And FProducts.Failed <> 0))
               .ToDictionary(Function(p) FProducts.Serial_number, Function(p) 0)
```

Comment: It requires expressions to work with a LINQ-To-Entities context.

Comment: How do I define the LINQ query with that? Sorry, I'm a little fuzzy on VB.Net lambda syntax, feels kind of awkward

Comment: @Reigo I've edited the answer to base it on your source code. NB LINQ query syntax (`from..where..select` etc) only supports a subset of methods, `ToDictionary` not being one of them. So you have to go back to using standard method calls for that one.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I have learned LINQ using C#, where the lamba expression was quite straight forward, in VB.Net its quite confusing to me at first.

Answer (score 1):

```
var products =  from p in FProducts select new { value=serial_number,key=productid};
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var item in products){
  dictionary.Add(item.value, item.key);
}
```